# Excel Conditional Formatting and SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I put this formula in a cell, it works, returning TRUE or FALSE:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Start]<=AK26)*(Table1[End]>=AK26))>0
```

But, when I try to put this same formula in a conditional formatting, I receive this error:

> "There's a problem with this formula"

Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks so much! But, I have a lot of cells to formato. Put the formula in the sheet is not a good option to this specifc case...

Comment: I have a dinamic "callendar" and a list of events with a interval of dates on each event. I need to format the cells that match the interval in order to show events in callendar

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when you reference a table in conditional formatting or data validation, you need to use INDIRECT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Table1[Start]")<=AK26)*(INDIRECT("Table1[End]")>=AK26))>0
```